# What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources

The JSF [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html), [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) and [`<h:graphicImage>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) components have a `library` attribute. What is this and how should this be used? There are a lot of examples on the web which use it as follows with the common content/file type `css`, `js` and `img` (or `image`) as library name depending on the tag used:

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js" />
<h:graphicImage library="img" name="logo.png" />
```

How is it useful? The `library` value in those examples seems to be just repeating whatever is already been represented by the tag name. For a `<h:outputStylesheet>` it's based on the tag name already obvious that it represents a "CSS library". What's the difference with the following which also just works the same way?

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="img/logo.png" />
```

Also, the generated HTML output is a bit different. Given a context path of `/contextname` and `FacesServlet` mapping on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml`, the former generates the following HTML with the library name as request parameter:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/script.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script>
<img src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/logo.png.xhtml?ln=img" alt="" />
```

While the latter generates the following HTML with the library name just in the path of the URI:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/css/style.css.xhtml" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/js/script.js.xhtml"></script>
<img src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/img/logo.png.xhtml" alt="" />
```

The latter approach makes in hindsight also more sense than the former approach. How exactly is the `library` attribute then useful?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Actually, all of those examples on the web wherein the common content/file type like "js", "css", "img", etc is been used as library name are **misleading**.

#### Real world examples

To start, let's look at how existing JSF implementations like [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) and [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org) and JSF component libraries like [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) and [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) use it. No one of them use resource libraries this way. They use it (under the covers, by [`@ResourceDependency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceDependency.html) or [`UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#addComponentResource(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent))) the following way:

```html
<h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
<h:outputScript library="omnifaces" name="omnifaces.js" />
<h:outputScript library="omnifaces" name="fixviewstate.js" />
<h:outputScript library="omnifaces.combined" name="[dynamicname].js" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces" name="primefaces.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-aristo" name="theme.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-vader" name="theme.css" />
```

It should become clear that it basically represents the **common library/module/theme name** where all of those resources commonly belong to.

#### Easier identifying

This way it's so much easier to specify and distinguish where those resources belong to and/or are coming from. Imagine that you happen to have a `primefaces.css` resource in your own webapp wherein you're overriding/finetuning some default CSS of PrimeFaces; if PrimeFaces didn't use a library name for its own `primefaces.css`, then the PrimeFaces own one wouldn't be loaded, but instead the webapp-supplied one, which would break the look'n'feel.

Also, when you're using a custom [`ResourceHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html), you can also apply more finer grained control over resources coming from a specific library when `library` is used the right way. If all component libraries would have used "js" for all their JS files, how would the `ResourceHandler` ever distinguish if it's coming from a specific component library? Examples are OmniFaces [`CombinedResourceHandler`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/CombinedResourceHandler.java#L280) and [`GraphicResourceHandler`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/GraphicResourceHandler.java#L48); check the `createResource()` method wherein the library is checked before delegating to next resource handler in chain. This way they know when to create `CombinedResource` or `GraphicResource` for the purpose.

Noted should be that RichFaces did it wrong. It didn't use any `library` at all and homebrewed another resource handling layer over it and it's therefore impossible to programmatically identify RichFaces resources. That's exactly the reason why [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`CombinedResourceHander`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler) had to introduce [a reflection-based hack](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Hacks.java#L228) in order to get it to work anyway with RichFaces resources.

#### Your own webapp

Your own webapp does not necessarily need a resource library. You'd best just omit it.

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="img/logo.png" />
```

Or, if you really need to have one, you can just give it a more sensible common name, like "default" or some company name.

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript library="default" name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage library="default" name="img/logo.png" />
```

Or, when the resources are specific to some master Facelets template, you could also give it the name of the template, so that it's easier to relate each other. In other words, it's more for self-documentary purposes. E.g. in a `/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml` template file:

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="layout" name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript library="layout" name="js/script.js" />
```

And a `/WEB-INF/templates/admin.xhtml` template file:

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="admin" name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript library="admin" name="js/script.js" />
```

For a real world example, check the [OmniFaces showcase source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase).

Or, when you'd like to share the same resources over multiple webapps and have created a "common" project for that based on the same example as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738) which is in turn embedded as JAR in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`, then also reference it as library (name is free to your choice; component libraries like OmniFaces and PrimeFaces also work that way):

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="common" name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript library="common" name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage library="common" name="img/logo.png" />
```

#### Library versioning

Another main advantage is that you can apply resource library versioning the right way on resources provided by your own webapp (this doesn't work for resources embedded in a JAR). You can create a direct child subfolder in the library folder with a name in the `\d+(_\d+)*` pattern to denote the resource library version.

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- default
 |         `-- 1_0
 |              |-- css
 |              |    `-- style.css
 |              |-- img
 |              |    `-- logo.png
 |              `-- js
 |                   `-- script.js
 :
```

When using this markup:

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript library="default" name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage library="default" name="img/logo.png" />
```

This will generate the following HTML with the library version as `v` parameter:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/css/style.css.xhtml?ln=default&amp;v=1_0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/js/script.js.xhtml?ln=default&amp;v=1_0"></script>
<img src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/img/logo.png.xhtml?ln=default&amp;v=1_0" alt="" />
```

So, if you have edited/updated some resource, then all you need to do is to copy or rename the version folder into a new value. If you have multiple version folders, then the JSF `ResourceHandler` will automatically serve the resource from the highest version number, according to numerical ordering rules.

So, when copying/renaming `resources/default/1_0/*` folder into `resources/default/1_1/*` like follows:

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- default
 |         |-- 1_0
 |         |    :
 |         |
 |         `-- 1_1
 |              |-- css
 |              |    `-- style.css
 |              |-- img
 |              |    `-- logo.png
 |              `-- js
 |                   `-- script.js
 :
```

Then the last markup example would generate the following HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/css/style.css.xhtml?ln=default&amp;v=1_1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/js/script.js.xhtml?ln=default&amp;v=1_1"></script>
<img src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/img/logo.png.xhtml?ln=default&amp;v=1_1" alt="" />
```

This will force the webbrowser to request the resource straight from the server instead of showing the one with the same name from the cache, when the URL with the changed parameter is been requested for the first time. This way the endusers aren't required to do a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5 and so on) when they need to retrieve the updated CSS/JS resource.

Please note that library versioning is not possible for resources enclosed in a JAR file. You'd need a custom `ResourceHandler`. See also [How to use JSF versioning for resources in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143383/how-to-use-jsf-versioning-for-resources-in-jar).

#### See also:

- [JSF resource versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929417/jsf-resource-versioning)
- [JSF2 Static resource caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362942/jsf2-static-resource-caching)
- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)
- [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) - Chapter 2.6 Resource Handling

Comment: Is it possible to use EL for the library?  So if I wanted to have a resources/default and a resources/feelingFroggyToday I could do something like library="#{someLibraryHere}"  map someLibraryHere to my chosen library and not have to rely on renaming the resources directory to a higher version every time I wanted to change them.

Comment: When you say library=admin or libray=layout, are those (admin and layout) folders in resources folder?

Comment: Umm. Very interesting Balus. I'm facing a problem in a web app where the theme.css file apear empty when loading. This only happens after various redeploys (in JBOSS EAP). The css url is like this: /javax.faces.resource/css/theme.css.xhtml?ln=default&v=3_3_0_130416 and it is declared this way: <h:outputStylesheet    library="default"    name="css/theme.css"    target="head" />. Maybe this issue is related to versioning issues?

Comment: I am using versioning concept with respect to css in my application. Though the correct, that is, the latest version is getting picked, the version is not getting appended in the  generated HTML. I am using primefaces 5.3. Has anything changed ?

Comment: Did the allowed characters for the value of `library` or something related to it change between mojarra 2.2.5( 2.2.5-jbossorg-3, wildfly 8.0) and 2.2.11(2.2.11-jbossorg-1)? I cannot seem to find anything in the releasenotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719808/wildfly-10-issue-with-css-file

Comment: @Kukeltje: Possibly. That's only good as the `library` doesn't represent a path in first place.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Unfortunately even Oracle's own Java EE 7 Tutorial gives the wrong example by using a library name `css` in the chapter [8.6 Web Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets006.htm#GIRGM) and doing it wrong with css and images in the [guessnumber-jsf example application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets003.htm).

Comment: If you are like me and want to check for yourself the pattern expected for versions, here it is: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/resource/ResourceHelper.java. RESOURCE_VERSION_PATTERN =
          Pattern.compile("^((?:\\d+)(?:_\\d+)+)[\\.]?(\\w+)?");

Comment: I encountered an issue where the files in my resources subfolders did not load *when the context root was set to an empty String* -> /
Changing from <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" /> to <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" /> fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, Can i use `library` attribute for i18n? i found [this](http://omnifaces-fans.blogspot.com/2015/01/jsf-22-resources-and-resourcehandlers.html), should i follow?

Comment: @Arash: nope there is no need to copy paste the current locale into the library over all place, just adjust folder structure as instructed in the link you found, the rest is automatic.